# "Tengo este error en la linea var marvel_api" :Syntax error : unexpected comma and the end of statement

Tags: go

data, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(responseExternalAPI.Body) 
    var marvel_api domain.Characters,err3 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data),&marvel_api)
    if err1 != nil || err2 != nil || err3 != nil {
        return domain.Characters{},err
    }

Comment: Deberías incluir más información sobre el error, para ayudar a otros usuarios a responder esto. Siguiendo con la respuesta, creo es por que tienes esto `var marvel_api domain.Characters,err3 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data),&marvel_api)` deberia ser `var marvel_api domain.Characters{}
err3 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data),&marvel_api)` y creo yo deberia de funcionar :D

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende el codigo pero puede ser que el problema sea que en go si realizas código multilinea debes de poner como al finalizar cada linea para indicar que es parte de la misma linea.

En una sola linea:

```
miFuncion(var1,var2)
```

Multi linea :

```
    miFuncion(
        var1,
        var2,
    )
```

Para Metodos:

miestructura.miFuncion(var1,var2)

```
miestructura.
    MiFuncion(
       var1,
       var2,
    )
```